Magento 2 : Create event observer when order placed and updated
In Magento 2, How to create event and observer for the REST API when an order is placed or updated.
Is this possible to create event and observer for REST API?.
If not, could anyone provide me with the correct solution.

Can you specify which things actually you want to do with Event? So we can suggest accordingly.

I want to retrieve order details whenever an order is placed or updated in Magento. Currently, I am working on integrating orders with CRM. Therefore, whenever an order is created or updated in Magento, I need to receive the specific details of that order. Destination should be my function's REST API URL.

For new order place you can use this event "sales_order_place_after"
Step 1: Create events.xml file at

app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml



<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="mycustom_place_order_after" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\Orderplaceafterobserver"/>
    </event>
</config>

Step 2:  Create Orderplaceafterobserver.php at

app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\Orderplaceafterobserver.php

<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Orderplaceafterobserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            // APPLY Logic here for your requirements
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

